Reminders app different on iPhone vs MacOS/iPadOS
The reminders app on my iPhone (11PM) seems to be in a completely different universe vs the reminders app on my Macbook Air (M1) and iPad Pro (M1). Plus the iPhone's reminders app does not have any of the newer features such as smart lists. Help appreciated to sort it out. Screenshots below.




Do they have the latest version of system software?

@hym3242 - software on all devices fully updated. However, I was able to resolve the issue - have posted the solution as answer.

Upon further reading online - I understood that Reminders had been upgraded sometime back to include features like Smart Lists and Subtasks. For regular users of Reminders - they would have got an 'upgrade' message in their iOS apps around that time. In my case, I had never used Reminders app previously and this was the first time I was using it. For some reason, the iOS app did not ask me to 'upgrade' reminders.
The issue was resolved by:

Going into iCloud settings on my iPhone
Disabling sync for Reminders
Reenabling sync for Reminders
Refresh the app


Indeed. I guess the software glitched and missed a migration/upgrade.
